# Como gerar comparações OR dinamicamente com LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-v1

Tenho uma `query` onde devo buscar certos valores comparando se uma coluna é igual a um valor **X**.

**X** é um array que pode ter de 1 à 4 valores.

Como eu posso na minha `query` com `LINQ` montar dinamicamente esses `OR`?

Abaixo segue como está meu código:

```
public List<Meta> ListaMetasDeCategorias(List<CategoriaMetaOrgao> ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao, int orgaoId, int temporadaId)
{
    List<int> arrayIdCategorias = new List<int>();
    foreach(CategoriaMetaOrgao categoriaMetaOrgao in ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao)
        arrayIdCategorias.Add(categoriaMetaOrgao.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId);

    var q = from a in Repository.Context.Meta
            where a.Temporada.temporadaId == temporadaId
            && a.Orgao.orgaoId == orgaoId
            && (a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId == arrayIdCategorias[0] ||
            a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId == arrayIdCategorias[1] ||
            a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId == arrayIdCategorias[2] ||
            a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId == arrayIdCategorias[3])
            select a;

    return q.ToList();
}
```

No trecho abaixo, como eu posso fazer a comparação dinamicamente? Pois o array nem sempre terá os 4 valores.

```
a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId == arrayIdCategorias[0] ||
a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId == arrayIdCategorias[1] ||
a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId == arrayIdCategorias[2] ||
a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId == arrayIdCategorias[3]
```

Comment: Qual a versão do EF e do .Net Framework que você está utilizando?

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida EF 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você utiliza a versão 1 do **Entity Framework**, também conhecida como versão 3.5, eu vejo 2 possibilidades para resolver o problema.

**1. Uma delas é criar um método de extensão para isso.**

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereIn<TEntity, TValue>
(
    this ObjectQuery<TEntity> query,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> selector,
    IEnumerable<TValue> collection
)
{
    if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
    if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    if (!collection.Any())
        return query.Where(t => false);

    ParameterExpression p = selector.Parameters.Single();

    IEnumerable<Expression> equals = collection.Select(value =>
       (Expression)Expression.Equal(selector.Body,
            Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue))));

    Expression body = equals.Aggregate((accumulate, equal) =>
        Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));

    return query.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, p));
}
```

Para usa-la:

```
public List<Meta> ListaMetasDeCategorias(List<CategoriaMetaOrgao> ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao, int orgaoId, int temporadaId)
{
    List<int> arrayIdCategorias = new List<int>();
    foreach(CategoriaMetaOrgao categoriaMetaOrgao in ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao)
        arrayIdCategorias.Add(categoriaMetaOrgao.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId);

    var q = from a in Repository.Context.Meta
            where a.Temporada.temporadaId == temporadaId
            && a.Orgao.orgaoId == orgaoId
            select a;

    q.WhereIn(a => a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId, arrayIdCategorias);

    return q.ToList();
}
```

**2. A outra solução e que eu não recomendo muito é transformar sua query para uma lista e depois fazer o filtro do `Contains`, o problema dessa maneira é que você não está fazendo o filtro no select, assim, talvez tornando sua consulta mais pesada.**

```
public List<Meta> ListaMetasDeCategorias(List<CategoriaMetaOrgao> ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao, int orgaoId, int temporadaId)
{
    List<int> arrayIdCategorias = new List<int>();
    foreach(CategoriaMetaOrgao categoriaMetaOrgao in ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao)
        arrayIdCategorias.Add(categoriaMetaOrgao.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId);

    var q = from a in Repository.Context.Meta
            where a.Temporada.temporadaId == temporadaId
            && a.Orgao.orgaoId == orgaoId
            select a;

    var y = q.ToList().Where( a => arrayIdCategorias.Contains(a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId));


    return y;
}
```

**Obs:**
Caso você utilizasse o **Entity Framework 4** ou superior, você poderia usar o `Contains`, ele pega uma lista e verifica se um elemento está nessa lista.

```
public List<Meta> ListaMetasDeCategorias(List<CategoriaMetaOrgao> ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao, int orgaoId, int temporadaId)
{
    List<int> arrayIdCategorias = new List<int>();
    foreach(CategoriaMetaOrgao categoriaMetaOrgao in ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao)
        arrayIdCategorias.Add(categoriaMetaOrgao.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId);

    var q = from a in Repository.Context.Meta
            where a.Temporada.temporadaId == temporadaId
            && a.Orgao.orgaoId == orgaoId
            && arrayIdCategorias.Contains(a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId)
            select a;

    return q.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo. Deu o erro: "LINQ to Entities não reconhece o método 'Boolean Contains(Int32)', que não pode ser convertido em uma expressão de armazenamento."

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann qual a versão do seu Entity Framework?

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann o EF 3.5 não suporta o Contains, vou bolar outra resposta para você

Comment: Legal, tentei a segunda sugestão e funcionou. Mas por que acha que a consulta poderia ficar mais pesada com essa opção? Depois que fiz a consulta a trouxe a lista não farei outra consulta no banco, simplesmente filtrarei a lista gerada pela query. Isso não teria impacto significativo na performance, correto?

Comment: @GeorgeWurthmann o Ideal é sempre fazer os filtros antes de retornar a lista, para que n traga dados desnecessários, dependendo do filtro isso pode fazer uma diferença de muitos dados e com isso a query vai ficar mais pesada, não quer dizer que vai acontecer isso, mas é uma possibilidade. Note que no seu problema eu fiz todos os filtros que podiam antes para depois fazer o outro, assim já vai trazer uma quantidade reduzida de dados otimizando sua consulta.

Comment: Não existe Entity Framework 3.5. Por favor, ajuste a resposta para [a versão mais antiga do Entity Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.1.10311).

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez existe sim, a primeira versão do EF é conhecida como 3.5 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574253(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Então, esse nome "EF 3.5" é uma baita barra forçada. É sim a primeira versão, mas ela deveria ser chamada "EF sobre .NET 3.5". No SOen, eles chamam apenas de EF v1, justamente porque é a primeira. Acho que vou recriar a tag como um sinônimo pra evitar essas coisas.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez mas o propio site da MS chama ele de 3.5 tb, na verdade ele é conhecido como EF ou EF 3.5, n sei o motivo disso

Comment: Justamente isso que te falei. O primeiro EF é em cima de .NET 3.5, e é um terror. Esse nome só atrapalha, na real.

Answer (score 1):

A `List` chamada de `arrayIdCategorias` possui o método `Any` onde ele vai varrer o `array` em busca de satisfazer a condição.

No caso abaixo, ele varre o `arrayIdCategorias` buscando se há algum valor `int` que seja igual a `a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId`.

Caso ele encontre o `Any` retorna `true`, se não `false`.

```
public List<Meta> ListaMetasDeCategorias(List<CategoriaMetaOrgao> ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao, int orgaoId, int temporadaId)
{
    List<int> arrayIdCategorias = new List<int>();
    foreach(CategoriaMetaOrgao categoriaMetaOrgao in ListaCategoriaMetaOrgao)
        arrayIdCategorias.Add(categoriaMetaOrgao.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId);

    var q = from a in Repository.Context.Meta
        where a.Temporada.temporadaId == temporadaId
        && a.Orgao.orgaoId == orgaoId
        && arrayIdCategorias.Any(b=>b == a.CategoriaMeta.categoriaMetaId)
        select a;

    return q.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Com o any deu certo, mas o q.Tolist que deu erro agora: "Não foi possível criar um valor constante de tipo 'Tipo de fechamento'. Há suporte apenas para tipos primitivos ('como Int32, String ou Guid') nesse contexto."

Comment: Acredito que o erro que deu no retorno seja devido a versão 3.5 do meu EF. Mas com certeza a resposta ajudará outros usuários com versões superiores.